# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser . not returning "href" attribute from anchor tags

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get all URL's from a html source, however the payload that is returned doesn't bring the "href" attribute.

This is my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$foundHits = array();
getArticles('https://pinpoint.microsoft.com/pt-PT/search?keyword=azure');


function getArticles($page) {
    global $foundHits;

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($page);

    $hits = $html->find('div[class="companySearchResults"] div[class="itemRight"] a[class=searchResult]');


    foreach($hits as $hit) {

        $foundHits[] = $hit->attr['href'];
    }

    var_dump($foundHits);
}
```

And this is a sample of what is returned if I var_dump $hits variable:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(simple_html_dom_node)[447]
      public 'nodetype' => int 1
      public 'tag' => string 'a' (length=1)
      public 'attr' => 
        array (size=2)
          'data-bind' => string 'href: uri + '?id=searchResult'' (length=30)
          'class' => string 'searchResult' (length=12)
      public 'children' => 

(...)
```

Has you can see, in the "attr" array I don't get the href tag content, despite existing.

However if I copy the contents from the source URL to a .html in my project folder, and use this local .html as my source file the result is this:

```
0 => 
    object(simple_html_dom_node)[650]
      public 'nodetype' => int 1
      public 'tag' => string 'a' (length=1)
      public 'attr' => 
        array (size=3)
          'data-bind' => string 'href: uri + '?id=searchResult'' (length=30)
          'class' => string 'searchResult' (length=12)
          'href' => string '/pt-PT/Companies/4295470302?id=searchResult' (length=43)

(...)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should include a html snippet and try to narrow down your question a bit.